# OutOfMemoryException after CameraCaptureDialog - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, bitmap, camera, compact-framework, out-of-memory

I'm developping an application for a [PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_digital_assistant) using the Compact Framework (Windows Mobile 6.1). I need to make photos and to display images. So, to make a photo i'm using the `CameraCaptureDialog` class:

```
using (var dialog = new CameraCaptureDialog())
{
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And to display an image a use a `Form`:

```
public partial class FormImageViewer : Form
{
    public FormImageViewer(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException();

        InitializeComponent();

        // Here I have an OutOfMemoryException!
        image = new Bitmap(fileName);
    }


    private Bitmap image;


    private void menuItemOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(image != null)
            image.Dispose();

        GC.Collect();
        Close();
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        double ratio = Math.Max((double)image.Width / Width, (double)image.Height / Height);
        int x = (Width - (int)(image.Width / ratio)) / 2;
        int y = (Height - (int)(image.Height / ratio)) / 2;

        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(x, y, (int)(image.Width / ratio), (int)(image.Height / ratio));
        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

The problem is the `OutOfMemoryException` that is only thrown if first I used the `CameraCaptureDialog` class. If I don't do photos there is not any exception.

Why? How can I fix this problem?